JoinFaces 5.2.4 with Spring Boot 3.2.4 - Weld warnings
We have a web application running PrimeFaces on Spring Boot with the primefaces-spring-boot-starter from JoinFaces. After upgrading from Spring Boot 2.x (deployed as a WAR with external Tomcat) to 3.2.4 with the corresponding JoinFaces 5.2.4 version (now deployed as a JAR with embedded Tomcat), a few Weld related warnings started to appear periodically in our application logs:
WARN  org.jboss.weld.Servlet - WELD-000715: HttpContextLifecycle guard not set. The Servlet container is not fully compliant.
WARN  org.jboss.weld.Servlet - WELD-000714: HttpContextLifecycle guard leak detected. The Servlet container is not fully compliant. The value was 1
WARN  org.jboss.weld.Context - WELD-000225: Bean store leak detected during org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpRequestContextImpl association: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6ac1196a
WARN  org.jboss.weld.Context - WELD-000225: Bean store leak detected during org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl association: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6ac1196a
WARN  org.jboss.weld.Conversation - WELD-000335: Conversation context is already active, most likely it was not cleaned up properly during previous request processing: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6ac1196a

If we set the servlet context parameter org.jboss.weld.context.ignore.guard to false the warnings disappear but we're not entirely sure if it is the right way to tackle the problem.
Any suggestions on how to handle these warnings?
Thanks!
